# Regex that grabs variable number of groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

This is not a question asking how to use `re.findall()` or the global modifier `(?g)` or `\g`. This is asking how to match `n` groups with one regex expression, with `n` between 3 and 5.

Rules:

- needs to ignore lines with first non-space character as `#` (comments)
- needs to get at least three items, always in order: `ITEM1`, `ITEM2`, `ITEM3`

  - `class ITEM1(stuff)`
  - `model = ITEM2`
  - `fields = (ITEM3)`
- needs to get any of the following matches if they exist (UNKNOWN order, and can be missing)

  - `write_once_fields = (ITEM4)`
  - `required_fields = (ITEM5)`
- needs to know which match is which, so either retrieve matches in order, returning `None` if there is no match, or retrieve pairs.

My question is if this is doable, and how?

I've gotten this far, but it hasn't dealt with comments or unknown order or if some items are missing and to stop searching for this particular regex when you see the next `class` definition.  https://www.regex101.com/r/cG5nV9/8

```
(?s)\nclass\s(.*?)(?=\()
.*?
model\s=\s(.*?)\n
.*?
(?=fields.*?\((.*?)\))
.*?
(?=write_once_fields.*?\((.*?)\))
.*?
(?=required_fields.*?\((.*?)\))
```

Do I need a conditional?

Thanks for any kinds of hints.

Comment: This seems poorly-suited to regex. You should be parsing this instead.

Comment: @AdamSmith Is there a way to parse it without regex?

Comment: AdamSmith is right, just loop through the lines in the file, skip if they start with '#', and select a function to parse the line based on its first word.  You can build a list of pairs or whatever and validate the result afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

comment_line = re.compile(r"\s*#")
matches = defaultdict(dict)

with open('path/to/file.txt') as inf:
    d = {} # should catch and dispose of any matching lines
           # not related to a class
    for line in inf:
        if comment_line.match(line):
            continue # skip this line
        if line.startswith('class '):
            classname = line.split()[1]
            d = matches[classname]
        if line.startswith('model'):
            d['model'] = line.split('=')[1].strip()
        if line.startswith('fields'):
            d['fields'] = line.split('=')[1].strip()
        if line.startswith('write_once_fields'):
            d['write_once_fields'] = line.split('=')[1].strip()
        if line.startswith('required_fields'):
            d['required_fields'] = line.split('=')[1].strip()
```

You could probably do this easier with regex matching.

```
comment_line = re.compile(r"\s*#")
class_line = re.compile(r"class (?P<classname>)")
possible_keys = ["model", "fields", "write_once_fields", "required_fields"]
data_line = re.compile(r"\s*(?P<key>" + "|".join(possible_keys) +
                       r")\s+=\s+(?P<value>.*)")

with open( ...
    d = {} # default catcher as above
    for line in ...
       if comment_line.match(line):
           continue
       class_match = class_line.match(line)
       if class_match:
           d = matches[class_match.group('classname')]
           continue # there won't be more than one match per line
       data_match = data_line.match(line)
       if data_match:
           key,value = data_match.group('key'), data_match.group('value')
           d[key] = value
```

But this might be harder to understand. YMMV.